# Allow multiple user to run the same exe

Tags: c#, .net, web, exe, multiple-instances

I'm building a program in visual studio 2010 using C# .Net.

I am wondering if there is a way to build a executable that allows multiple users to run it at the same time.

Basically, the executable is built and available online. When the user access the site, he can use the executable. However, when multiple users try to access the site and access the same exe, it breaks.

I couldn't really identify the issue. When I run the exe on 2 separate command line prompt, they both run as expected, but when running from the website, it breaks.

Any idea what could be the cause and how to fix it?

-- Edit 3:40pm --

The way the site works is the the site will call a java program, and the java program will call my exe, and then return some data to the the site.

The java will call the exe using the command line argument `program.exe arg1`

The executable is pulling some information from the server side, do some modification to the information, and then put the modified information on the site and display to user.

When I say it breaks, I mean the the site does not get any modified information and display nothing back for the user.

Comment: What is the executable doing? There could be some resource locking issue if they are all trying to access server-side resources. If you are running both from different command line prompts, they running (I'm assuming) on the same machine as the same user. That's not the same as two different users on different machines.

Comment: @kettch - The program is pulling information from the server side. The credential is used withing the code `NetworkCredential`, so I don't think the reason is user not being authorized.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that starts the exe. Also please explain more what the exe is doing and what does "breaks" mean. Is it throwing a exception? Is it giving a error message? Is it producing incorrect results?

Comment: if there is no any external resource update(reading is okay) operation (for example updating a file), feel free to invoke exe file many times with threads.

Comment: Can you explain what led you to needing to download an exe in order to do data processing? I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the concept. Is this some processing that could be done server side, within the existing Java application, or with client side script? Also, how is the exe communicating with the server? Direct DB access, services?

Comment: if each exe instance try to update part of the resource, it's okay too, maybe there is some transaction, or buffer that you just forgot to flush and commit it.